# OptaPlanner Examples doesn't work and gives error

Tags: runtime-error, optaplanner

When I try to open OptaPlanner Examples from examples.bat, interface comes to my screen. But when I click on a random example it gives error and doesn't work. It starts like;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:306)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:103)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:83)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.setSolver(SolutionBusiness.java:197)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:130)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:118)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/conferencescheduling/solver/RulesE771C4C7BDBE449D9F55BB1736BF1764RuleMethods2.java, line=355, column=74439
   text=ınt cannot be resolved to a type], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/conferencescheduling/solver/RulesE771C4C7BDBE449D9F55BB1736BF1764RuleMethods2.java, line=360, column=76059
   text=ınt cannot be resolved to a type], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/conferencescheduling/solver/RulesE771C4C7BDBE449D9F55BB1736BF1764RuleMethods2.java, line=0, column=0
   text=Java source of src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/conferencescheduling/solver/RulesE771C4C7BDBE449D9F55BB1736BF1764RuleMethods2.java in error:
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. The rest of the stacktrace, including the DRL error in the chained exception should give us a better idea what's going wrong. *Which JDK are use using?* Try `java --version`.

Comment: I am using JDK 11.0.11, I have all chain of errors on txt file but I do not know how to upload it to here. I do not know if operating system that I use cause to that. I also tried to start it from intelliJ IDE but same error occurs. I tried it on OptaPlanner's 3 different versions including 8.4.x, 8.3.x and the latest one 8.5.0.

Comment: Just 10 more lines of the stacktrace will probably include the actual issue

Comment: I am sending a link from google drive so you can read it all.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hg7tpQatmRc8pzFTSrr1CNuHZnHuKqe1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this error with the latest OptaPlanner downloaded from https://www.optaplanner.org.

Would you mind [reporting the issue](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER) with exact steps to reproduce it?